# Что не так с профайлером PHP Storm?

Tags: php, phpstorm, openserver, профилирование

Пытаюсь включить профайлер в связке Openserver + PHP Storm:

.ini файл у меня такой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После запуска скрипта в режиме дебага в temp/xdebug записался файл

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но когда я пытаюсь открыть, как я понимаю, снимок профайлера, то получаю ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как ни рылся в интернете, пока не смог понять, в чем-тут дело.. Не подскажете, кто лучше разбирается?

Comment: так это не файл профайлинга.... профайлер называется cachegrind.out.

Comment: Да, похоже на то, и что интересно, у меня в ini xdebug.remote_enable = 1, а если открыть файл, то там php_info xdebug.profiler_enable Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger On

Comment: Как вам сказали выше, этот файл для [cachegrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html)